# Quantum entanglement wins or black hole wins?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes

suppose: you have 2 particles "entangled" with each other, one of them is dropped by you into a black hole. Ignore any problems with the particle during its entry into the black hole. The outer particle is subjected to an impact sufficient to cause it to split. I have a question is there any way to know if the particle inside the black hole is affected like the particle outside?. Once again suppose, the outer particle is split. split into particles traveling at the speed of light, if there really are interactions between them, will the particle inside be split like the ones outside?.If yes, then as you know even light cannot escape from the black hole. So the split particles will definitely not be able to escape. In the opposite direction, will the outer particle suffer the same resistance as the inner particle?
(Note: All are just assumptions of a novice)

Comment: "Destroing" one entangled particle does not affect the other. Generally, nothing you do with one particle affects the other. Correlation is not causation.

Comment: What do you mean "destroy"? You can't really destroy a particle. You can annihilate it, but that is not the same thing. You can only turn it into something else.

Comment: That's why we have black hole [information paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox). If information inside black hole is destroyed, then affecting outer particle state, will not produce any changes on the information inside black hole, but then quantum mechanics gets broken, which says that coupled entangled state must be changed for both particles. But if QM is true, then information must be conserved inside black hole, for affecting inner particle,- alas this breaks general relativity theory then. That's why we need quantum gravity which doesn't exists yet.

Comment: If you take two entangled particles and destroy one of them, then nothing will happen to the other, whether it is in a black hole or not.

Comment: If you drop a particle to a black hole, you’ll never see it crossing the horizon. As you observe from outside, the particle remains outside the horizon forever and can always escape, if something pushes it out. Thus your question has no meaning.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas The information paradox does not arise without the black hole evaporating. The OP did not mention evaporation. So your comment does not apply.